# Woocommerce product filter displays dynamic product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I have used woocommerce product filter. When I'm refreshing the page it shows the products in random order.

Can someone help me to figure out how to display the same products in the same order when I refresh the product page?

```
<?php global $wp_query;
    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); ?>
    <?php if($image): ?>
        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
            <div class="interior-banner group" <?php if ( $image ) : ?>style="background:url(<?php echo $image;?>) no-repeat center;"<?php endif; ?>>
                <div class="background-mask">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1 class="title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
                        <h2 class="sub-title"><?php echo get_cat_name($cat->parent);?></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if($cat->description): ?>
                <div class="interior-banner-description">
                    <div class="content">
                        <p class="description"><?php echo $cat->description; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <div class="woocommerce-child-cat">
    <?php woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="child-cat-cover group ">
            <div class="left-column">
                <?php
                    global $wp_query;
                    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                    //product filter
                    echo '<h4 class="cat-title">'.$cat->name.'</h4>';
                    echo do_shortcode('[woof sid="product-filter" is_ajax=1 taxonomies=product_cat:'. $cat->term_id .']');
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="right-column">
                <?php echo do_shortcode('[woof_products per_page=12 columns=3 is_ajax=1 taxonomies=product_cat:'. $cat->term_id .']'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

            <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the query with 'pre_get_post' hook and add 'post_order' to the query on the product archive page [pre_get_post doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)
If you want to be more specific on the effect of the query modification use conditional tags for the product_archive page only.